# Not being able to pass webservice data to another viewcontroller after URL connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, viewcontroller

I want to pass json data that I received from the following url and pass "username" data to SecondViewController. I only want to pass data, when is connection made and successful.

I am having following problems:

1. No matter URL is right or wrong, I am getting directed to SecondViewController. I only want to go to SecondViewController, when connection is successful and data has been fetched.
2. And I am not able to receive data on the SecondViewController when I put following line inside of URL connection code:

`SecondViewController * destination=[segue destinationViewController];`

`destination.displayName=[info objectForKey:@"username"];`

If I place following code right before, NSURL it works and I see the message in the SecondViewController. But I pass `destination.displayName=@"Testing Message"`.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/?user_id=1"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
         {
             NSDictionary *info = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                      options:0
                                                                     error:NULL];
             //this is my second view controller
             SecondViewController * destination=[segue destinationViewController];

             destination.displayName=[info objectForKey:@"username"];

         }//if connected

     }];//end of connection

}//end of prepareforsegue
```

What is the best way to accomplish this? And is it right to place URL Connection code inside prepareForSegue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this solution:

```
- (void)fetchRequest {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/?user_id=1"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (data.length > 0 && !connectionError) {
            NSDictionary *info = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController" sender:info];
        }//if connected
    }];//end of connection
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SecondViewController"]) {
        if ([sender isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            //this is my second view controller
            SecondViewController * destination = [segue destinationViewController];
            destination.displayName=[sender objectForKey:@"username"];
        } // end of check on Sender Type
    } // end identifier check ..
}//end of prepareforsegue
```

Good luck with your app.

Comment: It says use of undeclared identifier 'info'. How can prepareForSegue will know about 'info'?

Comment: And where should I call `fetchRquest`?

Comment: when the user doing the interaction with interface or in viewDidLoad if you want to fetch request when user opening the FirsViewController

Comment: In `prepareForSegue`, it says use of undeclared identifier 'info'. It is not recognizing `destination.displayName=[info objectForKey:@"username"];` What should I do?

Comment: Ok, figured out. I just changed "info" to "sender" and created button and put my connection code there.